# SetTimeOut speeds Up with multiple tabs opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have a timer ticker on `Layout`(MVC4.0) (**With 1 Second Interval**) page and it works fine when only 1 page of website(**In one tab**) is opened

```
var timeOutMinutes = 10;
var timeOutSeconds = timeOutMinutes * 60;
localStorage.setItem("SessionCounter", timeOutSeconds);

var popUpShown = false;
var logOutCalled = false;

$(document).ready(function () {
  setInterval(TimerDecrement, 1000);
});

function TimerDecrement() {
    if (timeOutSeconds > 0) {
        if (parseInt(localStorage.getItem("SessionCounter"), 10) > 0) {
            timeOutSeconds = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("SessionCounter"), 10);
        }
        timeOutSeconds--;
        localStorage.setItem("SessionCounter", timeOutSeconds);
    }
    else {

        if (!logOutCalled) {
            logOutCalled = true;
            LogOut();
        }
        else {
            logOutCalled = true;
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = timeOutSeconds;
    document.getElementById("secondsIdle").innerHTML = timeOutSeconds;

    if (timeOutSeconds < 500) {
        //alert(history.length);
        popUpShown = true;
        $("#pnlPopup").dialog("open");
    }
    else {
        if ($("#pnlPopup").dialog("isOpen")) {
            popUpShown = false;
            $("#pnlPopup").dialog("close");
        }
    }
}
```

But when I open **multiple tabs** of website timer jumps to decrease quickly.

How can I maintain the timer to decrement Uniformly even if website is opened in **multiple tabs**?

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozf24ruz/1/)

Comment: If you are using sessionStorage for storing initial time count then this issue (rapid decrement from multiple tabs) will rises because sessioStorage is common for all tabs. You can use a simple javascript variable. Scope of that variable will different for all tabs and timer will work properly.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion..but I want the timer to be decrement uniformly on all tabs(if multiple opened). because when timer goes to zero '0', then I have to do some ajax call...

Comment: Simply store the 'start of the countdown'. Then the seconds since then can be computed base on the current time. This would also ensure 'uniformly' (based on whatever action occurs in *any* tab), assuming that the countdown intervals are to be shared.

Comment: user2864740 ..I have edited the code ..plz have a look

Comment: @user2864740 ..I have added fiddle link..please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the counter that is being decremented is common to all tabs, because it is kept in LocalStorage. So the solution really depends on what you intention is for the decrement counter.

If the intention is for each session (each tab) to have it's own separate counter, then you would be better served using a variable instead of LocalStorage -- or alternatively, use a unique session id for each counter in LocalStorage.

If the intention is to have all tabs share the same decrement counter, but for it to only be decremented once per second regardless of how many tabs are open, then perhaps you want to store the counter as well as the last decrement time.

EDIT: Here is a forked fiddle that might do what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/y68m4zwr/8/

The gist of it is to add:

```
var lastUpdated = localStorage.getItem("SessionCounterUpdatedOn"),
            now = new Date(), shouldCheck = false;

        if (lastUpdated == null) {
            localStorage.setItem("SessionCounterUpdatedOn", now);
        } else if (now.getTime() - new Date(lastUpdated).getTime() >= 1000) {
            // set this immediatedly so another tab checking while we are processing doesn't also process.
            localStorage.setItem("SessionCounterUpdatedOn", now);
            shouldCheck = true;
        }
```

which checks for a last updated record for the counter and it if was updated less that second ago, it just updates the time left, otherwise performs the logic to decrement.

Comment: Thanks GPicazo..My intention is to share common counter to all tabs regardless of how many tabs are opened

Comment: I have added fiddle link..please have a look

Comment: I've forked your fiddle, let me know if it works (linked in answer).